# Fortran subroutine: How to load data only on first call

Tags: fortran, large-data, subroutine

I am programming a Fortran module, which is linked to external main program. I can only alter the subroutine. I have to detail a lot of data, but always the same. It takes too much time to do this on every call of the subroutine. How can I initialise the data only at the first call? 
Currently, this is the subroutine:

```
subroutine sdvini(statev,coords,nstatv,ncrds,noel,npt,layer,kspt)
implicit none  

integer imdat(100,100,50)

imdat(1,1,1:33)=(/1,8,13,24,48,72,111,148,156,165,182&
&,189,194,207,210,216,236,247,254,270,311,319,339,343,367,376&
&,393,397,421,438,447,473,492/)
.
. lots of data
. 

do something
return
end
```

Comment: That much data belongs in an external file which might be read on the first call to the subroutine and saved for subsequent calls. Do you need help to write the code to implement this approach ?  I don't have time to write it for you at the moment but look at some Qs and As hereabouts on the topics of Fortran''s `save` attribute for procedure variables.

Comment: The hint to the save attribute will be enough of this is really what indeed. I will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting of values on the first call to a procedure and retaining the values can be performed by explicit *initialization*.  We often use the term initialization, as in this question, to mean an assignment as part of a setting up process.  However, initialization means something more precise in Fortran terms.

An explicit initialization suitable for this question would be something like the very simple case

```
integer, save :: i=1   ! SAVE attribute would be implied, but made explicit
```

This is like having the assignment applied the first time the procedure is entered.

We can also use a data statement:

```
integer, save :: i
data i /1/
```

The SAVE attribute is what ensures that the value persists between entries to the procedure.

For arrays the idea is the same, perhaps using array constructors and `reshape`.

For very large arrays it is impractical to use data statements or initializers.  Further, there are restrictions on what may appear in initializing a saved local variable.  However, another idiom would be like

```
subroutine sub
  logical, save :: firsttime=.TRUE.
  integer, save :: obj(100,100,50)

  if (firsttime) then
    obj = ...  ! Setting the value somehow, maybe even with a read
    firsttime = .FALSE.
  end if
end subroutine
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and report back!